# Make VM from OS on old Hard Drive

Tags: virtualbox

I just got a new hard drive. I cloned my old drive over to the new one and am now running off the new hard drive. However the old hard drive is still installed and is listed as a drive I can boot from. I've tried it and it works, I can boot from either drive, the old one is just kind of a snap shot of my drive from before I cloned to the new.

So I was wondering, is there a way to run the OS from my old hard drive in virtualbox?

Like I'm still running off my new drive, but I want to load up my old hard drive via virtualbox. Is that possible. I found some instructions on mounting a raw disk and tried that, but it errors when I open it up. The command was

`VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename "C:\Users\hooper\VirtualBox VMs\VMs\olddrive.vmdk" -rawdisk .PhysicalDrive0`

Any suggestions on how to get this to work? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure about mounting a physical drive to a VM, sound risky to me (risky of disk corruption.) But you can image your physical drive to a virtual drive file and boot the VM from that.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, you can create an "bootable VM image" from the old hard drive and store it somewhere (in your new drive, maybe?) - then you can spinoff the VM using VirtualBox and run it next to your new drive..